# Wayland Scaling

Tags: wayland, dpi

Im playing around with wayland (on Fedora 24) and multi-dpi screens.

With X I am settings my secondary non HDPI screen to scaled with `xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto --output DP-1-8 --auto --panning 3840x2400+3840+0 --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1`

How can I make my secondary monitor scale with Wayland? (or achieve a reasonable experience on multi DPI screens with wayland)

Comment: I've observed that the my terminal windows automatically rescale when I drag them between my HiDPI laptop panel and an external regular-DPI monitor. I'm not sure whether that's a result of the compositor or the application toolkit, but you may need to specify which you're using. I'm using the GNOME 3 compositor and Gtk+ apps, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`xrandr` is not able to change Wayland settings. `xrandr` is a commandline utility for accessing XRandR compliant servers (such as XOrg for example). Wayland ditches most of that. Instead, you have Wayland running as part of the window managers themselves (mutter for GNOME, for example).

[This blog post](https://vizzzion.org/blog/2016/08/multisceen-in-plasma-improved-tools-and-debugging/) discusses some of the work that KDE is doing to write a screen management abstraction layer over X11 and Wayland.